# Firebase Cloud Function not triggering onCreate

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Trying to handle a contact form submission with Cloud Functions to send the email. The 'Hello World' function fired ok, so I think the set up is fine. The form populates the 'messages' collection, but I'm not getting a log entry (or error) for the trigger on the following:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const ref = admin.database().ref();

//if user contacts us
exports.sendContactEmail = functions.database
.ref('messages/{msgId}')
.onCreate(event => {

   console.log('Made it to the trigger!');
   const formData = event.data.data(); // the contact form data

   return sendContactEmail(formData);
})

// Sends an email to someone at the company
function sendContactEmail(formInfo) {
   console.log('Made it to the send function!');
   ...
```

package.json looks like:

```
"dependencies": {
   "firebase-admin": "~5.8.1",
   "firebase-functions": "^0.8.1",
```

Comment: Your use of the term "collection" and the code `event.data.data()` makes me guess that you want a [Firestore trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#trigger_a_function_when_a_new_document_is_created) and not the Realtime Database trigger that you have.  Is that right?

Comment: And, on that note, maybe also indicate exactly the change you're making that expects the trigger to be executed.

Comment: That is correct, I'm using Firestore. The trigger would be when the Angular 5 reactive contact form creates a new document in the messages collection, which is happening as expected.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The posted code is for a Realtime Database trigger.  To trigger the function on creation of a Firestore document, change the code to this:

```
//if user contacts us
exports.sendContactEmail = functions.firestore  // <= CHANGED
.document('messages/{msgId}')  // <= CHANGED
.onCreate(event => {

   console.log('Made it to the trigger!');
   const formData = event.data.data(); // the contact form data

   return sendContactEmail(formData);
})
```

Comment: Face-palm. I bet I could have looked at that for a week and not seen it. Thank you!