# Firebase Cloud Function not trigging - using onCreate - Google Cloud Console

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have searched multiple answers on stackoverflow but cannot seem to find one to solve my problem.
I am trying to get my cloud function to run when I create certain new data in Firebase Realtime Database.

[image: Screenshot of Database]

The function deploys fine and shows no errors, but the problem is that when I add data (like the data in the attachment), the function isn't triggered?
The data is created new, not updated.

Here is the code function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.pushNotificationFromAdmin = functions.database.ref('pushNotifications/{createdID}').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
  const data = snapshot.val();
  const topic = data.pushGroup.toString();
  const title = data.pushTitle;
  const body = data.pushBody;

  const payload = {
          notification : {
              title: title,
              body: body,
              mutable_content: 'true',
          },
  };

  const options = {
            priority : 'high',
            timeToLive : 60 * 60 * 2
  };
  console.log('Payload is : ' + payload)
  console.log('Sending to Topic ' + topic)
  return admin.messaging().sendToTopic(topic, payload, options);

});
```

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: can you refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48999651/15774176) , is it helpful?

Comment: hey @DivyaniYadav, thanks for the link, but that answer refers to firestore instead of realtime database. I am definitely using realtime database. 
Thank you though

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#handle_event_data) where mentioned as :

> When handling a Realtime Database event, the data object returned is a
> [DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_database.datasnapshot). For onWrite or onUpdate events, the first parameter
> is a Change object that contains two snapshots that represent the data
> state before and after the triggering event. For onCreate and onDelete
> events, the data object returned is a snapshot of the data created or
> deleted.
>
> In this example, the function retrieves the snapshot for the
> specified path as snap, converts the string at that location to
> uppercase, and writes that modified string to the database:
>
> ```
> // Listens for new messages added to /messages/:pushId/original and creates an
> // uppercase version of the message to /messages/:pushId/uppercase
> exports.makeUppercase = functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushId}/original')
>     .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
>       // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
>       const original = snapshot.val();
>       functions.logger.log('Uppercasing', context.params.pushId, original);
>       const uppercase = original.toUpperCase();
>       // You must return a Promise when performing asynchronous tasks inside a Functions such as
>       // writing to the Firebase Realtime Database.
>       // Setting an "uppercase" sibling in the Realtime Database returns a Promise.
>       return snapshot.ref.parent.child('uppercase').set(uppercase);
>     });
> ```

If you want to get more idea how to use triggers effectively for a realtime database , you can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59777595/15774176) and this [blog](https://medium.com/@hilaldiab/realtime-database-triggers-with-firebase-functions-26742641ddfa).

Comment: @OnlyDans Posted an answer, is it helpful?